# Similar concept to affine independence for vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, independence

In linear algebra there is the concept of affinely independent points. $N$ Points are affinely independent when any of the vectors produced by their piecewise difference are linearly independent.

For example if 3 points are in a 2D plane and $p_1 - p_2$ and $p_1 - p_3$ are linearly independent then $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are affinely independent.

I am looking for a similar concept. Given $k$ vectors in an $N$ dimensional space, the vectors obey the "simplex" property if there are $N+1$ vectors in the set such that for any subset of size $N$ the vectors span $\mathbb{R}^N$.

For example in 3D, if you have 30 vectors, and among those you have $e_1, e_2, e_3 (e_1+e_2+e_3)$. Then the set "obeys the simplex property", because any subset of 3 elements of the above 4 will necessarily span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I want to A) know if this has a name, B) know if there is a simple computational way of testing for it  given a large amount of vectors.

2D exmaples:

These 3 vectors obey the simplex property
[image]

These 3 do not:
[image]

Comment: By $n$ do you mean $N$?  This is highly confusing.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes that's what I meant. I am sorry if it is confusing, I am not sure how to explain it mathematically better. I will add a drawing, it might help.

Comment: @TedShifrin A different way to think about the problem is whether using the vectors you can construct a simplex polytope in N dimensions. e.e.g in 3D if you can find 4 vectors that could be the normals to the faces of a tetrahedron.

Comment: Dimension is still off, I believe. You need $N+1$ vectors, not $N$, to affinely span $\Bbb R^N$. Why are you not just saying that the affine span of the $k$ vectors is $\Bbb R^N$? Why so overcomplicated?

Comment: If the matrix formed by every $N$ sized subset of vectors has rank $N$, then the vectors are linearly independent and so should *linearly* span $\mathbb{R}^N$. Although I don't know if this is a computationally cheap method.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I did say N+1 in the question,  " if there are +1
 vectors in the set ".

It's complicated because the affine span and what I am saying are different. You will notice that in my drawings, in both cases the affine span of the vectors is a triangle, unless we have different definitions of an affine span.

But the firs timage shows a set of good vectors, sthe second image shows a set of bad vectors.

Comment: @TonyMathew That is ridiculously expensive computationally.

Comment: Another method that should work is this: First you fix $N$ vectors that make up a base, then express all other vectors you have in that base. If you find any vector that has now no 0-entry, then this and your base gives you the $N+1$-vectors set you want.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate a set of $N+1$ vectors $V = \{v_r\}_{r=1}^{N+1}$ in $\Bbb R^N$, form the $N+1 \times N$ matrix with $r$-th row $v_r^T$. Start doing Gaussian elimination to clear out the region below the diagonal. If at any point you have a row such that after you clear its currently-leading non-zero entry, the next leading entry moves more than one column back, the set of vectors fails. There will be a subset of $N$ vectors that does not span the entire space.

When this occurs with row $r$ skipping over column $c$, it indicates that vector $v_r$ can be expressed as
$$v_r = \sum_{i\ne r, c} a_{ri}v_i$$
Now if $V\setminus\{v_r\}$ is not linearly independent, $V$ fails the condition, but if it is linearly independent, it means that for all possible $\{b_i\}_i, v_c \ne \sum_{i\ne r,c} b_iv_i$.

But then if $V\setminus\{v_c\}$ were to be linearly independent, we would have $$v_c = \sum_{i\ne c} a_{ci}v_i = \sum_{i\ne r,c} a_{ci}v_i + a_{cr}\sum_{i\ne r,c} a_{ri}v_i$$
a contradiction. Thus, $V\setminus\{v_c\}$ and $V\setminus\{v_r\}$ cannot both be linearly independent. In either case, your condition is not met.